# Prettier - How to ignore certain file types in CLI file patterns?

Tags: filepath, prettier, filepattern

I want to exclude only `js`, `jsx`, and `vue` files, I imagine something like:

```sh
prettier --check --write --ignore-unknown "**/*.{!js,jsx,vue}"
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As it's said in the [Prettier CLI docs](https://prettier.io/docs/en/cli.html#file-patterns), Prettier uses [fast-glob](https://github.com/mrmlnc/fast-glob#pattern-syntax) (which in turn uses [micromatch](https://github.com/micromatch/micromatch)) to resolve glob patterns. If you follow the links, you'll find multiple ways to achieve what you need.

You can use negative patterns:

```sh
prettier --write --ignore-unknown '**' '!**/*.{js,jsx,vue}'
```

or

```sh
prettier --write . '!**/*.{js,jsx,vue}'
```

or you can use a syntax called [extglob](https://github.com/micromatch/micromatch#extglobs):

```sh
prettier --write --ignore-unknown '**/*.!(js|jsx|vue)'
```

There might be other solutions. fast-glob supports a lot of different things.

---

BTW, using `--write` and `--check` at the same time isn't a supported use case. Whatever it does, don't rely on that, and choose one of the two instead, depending on what you want the command to do:

- `--write` to format files
- `--check` to check if files are formatted (commonly used on CI)

Comment: Thanks, that was very informative. What if I want to check if files are formatted, if not, `--write` them? I suppose `--write` just writes everything without checking. Using `--write` with `--check` outputs a short message, whereas just `--write` will output everything that's been formatted, which is not what I wanted.

Comment: Apparently it works that way, but it's not documented.